# What does "ain't" mean?

Tags: meaning, formality, contractions, aint

What does the contraction *ain't* mean? Is it appropriate to use it in formal settings?

Comment: Related: [Why is “ain't” not listed in dictionaries?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1327/8183)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Ain't* is the same as *aren't* and means *are not* but it is also used for *am not, is not, has not, have not*.

It definitely should not be used in formal settings.

Comment: According to [@nohat's research](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1327/why-is-aint-not-listed-in-dictionaries/1343#1343) in the linked question, it started life as a contraction of _am not_ and _are not_ both.  I'm not quite sure how that works :-)

Comment: The only thing that surprises me is that while contracting such terms, from where does `i` in `ain't` popped up in between while contracting *am not* or *are not*? It should have simply been `an't`. Isn't it? Or may be possibly it also tried to represent `isn't` abbreviation.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere (it was a book on the history of English usage and editing though I can't find the source now) that *ain't* and *an't* started out as competing contractions for *am not* in the 1700s. However, the *ain't* pronunciation was more common among the "vulgar" population of England--thus earning the ire of the upper class and those who actually wrote books. This, in turn, lead to its damnation as a proper word which was picked up by early prescriptivists. The same source postulated that the phrase "Aren't I?" was originally "An't I?" as the two words sound very similar.

Answer (score 4):

From the Merriam-Webster:

> Main Entry: ain't
>   Pronunciation: \ˈānt\
>   Etymology: contraction of are not

Quoting @nohat :

> The common bit of schoolyard wisdom that “ain’t ain’t in the dictionary, so ain’t ain’t a word” turns out to be untrue. Every online dictionary that I’ve ever looked in contained an entry for ain’t.

It is a colloquial word, informal, so probably shouldn't be used in  formal settings,<s>unless you are a politican</s>:)

Comment: The OED lists it too (it even has two entries!)

Comment: Well LOL, OMG, and supercalifragilisticexpialidocious are in online dictionaries. Does that make them real words? Even 'haz' as in "I can haz cheezburger" is in Meriam Webster's online unabridged dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Replaceable with  am not, is not,  and are not. It used more informal/colloquial conversations.

Answer (score 0):

Ain't is the short form of :am not,is not,are not,has not,have not 
But it's not suitable to use it in formal speech

Comment: Did you read Hugo's answer before posting this answer? Your answer is almost 100% identical.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "am not" first, which is a key point that the other answers have missed; see  https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ain-t. The word was, mid-1700's, a recognized contraction for "am not". As people started using it for other grammatical persons, it became effectively banned completely. A shame, really; it would be much preferable to the ungrammatical "Aren't I?" which has somehow gained acceptance.