# Was “ain’t” at one time acceptable in “proper” English?

Tags: grammar, aint

I contend the word *ain’t* is a useful contraction of *am not*. ***Ain’t*** I correct in thinking that in the early 1800s, Bostonians thought of *ain’t* as an acceptable word without stigmatization?

Comment: This was recently addressed on [ell.SE](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/410/meaning-and-usage-of-aint). Until about the middle of the 19th century it was an ordinary colloquialism (usually spelled *an't* or *en't*) in all levels of society, though not used in formal writing (except of course in dramatic or fictional dialogue).

Answer (score 3):

Per [nohat's very thorough answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1327/why-is-aint-not-listed-in-dictionaries/1343#1343) to a previous question, the Online Etymology Dictionary [has the following to say about "ain't":](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ain%27t&searchmode=none)

> 1706, originally a contraction of *am not*, and in proper use with that sense until it began to be used as a generic contraction for *are not*, *is not*, etc., in early 19c. Cockney dialect of London; popularized by representations of this in Dickens, etc., which led to the word being banished from correct English.

In other words, yes, *ain't* used to be the proper contraction for "am not", but because certain lower-class dialects began to use this word for pretty much any contraction of [be] or [has] with [not], it acquired a bad reputation.

Answer (score 1):

This is still a very common colloquialism in the UK.

See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgUf9hlTnnU