# "I'm not" or "I amn't" or "I am not"?

Tags: negation

Does there exist a short form of *I am not*?

**I'm not** or **I amn't** or **I am not**?

Comment: __I'm not__, or __I am not__. Please also see [ell.se](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). In English, amn't is only used in some Scottish dialects, I believe; see [here](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-amn1.htm)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "ain't" mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33119/what-does-aint-mean). Also note [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/1343/2637) - **I ain't saying** it's *definitely* right, but apparently @nohat says [***ain't** started life as a contraction of both **am not** and **are not***](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33119/what-does-aint-mean#comment59935_33124)

Comment: *I'm not*.  Inverted *aren't I* is standard, but *\*I aren't* is not.  *I ain't* is nonstandard but generally recognized.  In some dialects *I amn't* is possible, but not generally.